# Tracing (for documentation purposes) through .cmd and .pl files.

Tags: perl, trace

I am somewhat new to programming and VERY to command line and perl.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a way that I can trace through a .cmd file and see what perl scripts its calling and then open those files and see what files it is calling (or functions etc...) without having to go through each file manually.  I use Visual Studio 2010 and Notepad.  I am mostly trying to do this to get everything documented and I would like to eventually be able to have a TOC or Tree View of the files and which files/commands/functions they call etc.. I am probably not explaining this well :)  So, apologies AND Thanks in advance!!  Britt

Comment: parsing CMD files may be easy (search for something like perl...), but parsing Perl files is harder. Try the PPI module (http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.215/lib/PPI.pm) and analyze if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The perl debugger will let you step through perl applications/scripts and see what is getting used with various levels of detail. See `perldoc perldebug` or the [online documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) for how that works.

[Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) is a nice (and free) IDE for perl and you can look at [other answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341191/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-2008-to-program-in-perl) for more ideas on how to use perl with VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing batch file is problematic: [Is there any way to trace through the execution of a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2366280)

For tracing Perl programs, install [Devel::Trace](http://p3rl.org/Devel::Trace) and set [`PERL5OPT=-d:Trace`](http://p3rl.org/perlrun#PERL5OPT).